# Error upon generating forest plot (Error: Assertion failed. One of the following must apply ..)

Tags: r, dplyr, r-forestplot

I am trying to create a forest plot but forestplot is giving me the error below. It was working before but not sure why not working now. here is an example where i create data table and then use `forestplot` and `dplyr` to generate a forestplot:

```
library(forestplot)
library(dplyr)

##Example SDAI-total cohort
base_data <- tibble(mean  = c(0.92, 0.86, 0.75, 0.77, 0.60),
                    lower = c(0.70, 0.35, 0.39, 0.44, 0.40),
                    upper = c(1.19, 2.14, 1.44, 1.34, 0.90),
                    study = c("STUDY1", "STUDY2", "STUDY3", "STUDY4", "STUDY5"),
                    N = c("160", "47", "167", "38", "146"),
                    HR = c('0.92 (0.70-1.19)', '0.86 (0.35-2.14)', '0.75 (0.39-1.4)', '0.77 (0.44-1.34)', '0.60 (0.40-0.90)'))

summary <- tibble(mean  = 0.78,
                  lower = 0.65,
                  upper = 0.95,
                  HR = '0.78 (0.65-0.95)',
                  study = "Summary")

header <- tibble(study = c("Study"),
                 N = c("N"),
                 HR = c("HR (95%CI)"),
                 summary = TRUE)

empty_row <- tibble(mean = NA_real_)

output <- bind_rows(header,
                    base_data,
                    empty_row,
                    summary)

output$summary[output$study=='Summary'] <- TRUE

output %>%
  forestplot(labeltext = c(study, N, HR),
             is.summary = summary,
             clip = c(0.35, 2.5),
             xticks=c(0.4,0.7,1,1.5,2,2.5),
             hrzl_lines = gpar(col = "#444444"),
             #hrzl_lines=list('2' = gpar(col='#444444')),
             xlog = TRUE,
             col = fpColors(box = "black",line = "black",summary = "darkred"),
             boxsize = 0.25,
             title='title',
             xlab = ('Hazard Ratio (log scale)'),
             align = 'l',
             txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label=gpar(fontsize=12),summary=gpar(fontsize=12),ticks=gpar(cex=1), xlab=gpar(cex=1)))
```

The error I am getting:

```
Error: Assertion failed. One of the following must apply:
 * check_matrix(mean): Must be of type 'matrix', not
 * 'tbl_df/tbl/data.frame'
 * check_array(mean): Must be of type 'array', not
 * 'tbl_df/tbl/data.frame'
 * check_integer(dim(mean)[2]): Element 1 is not <= 3
```

Sessioninf()

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.8.3     forestplot_1.9  checkmate_2.0.0 magrittr_1.5   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       fansi_0.4.0      crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.1
 [5] R6_2.4.1         lifecycle_0.2.0  backports_1.1.5  pillar_1.4.3    
 [9] cli_2.0.0        rlang_0.4.5      rstudioapi_0.11  vctrs_0.2.4     
[13] ellipsis_0.3.0   tools_3.6.3      glue_1.3.1       purrr_0.3.3     
[17] compiler_3.6.3   pkgconfig_2.0.3  tidyselect_0.2.5 tibble_3.0.1
```

How can we solve this in R?

Comment: You are using R < 4. If you updated / installed from CRAN after the release of R 4 it might lead to problems. Did you get warnings when installing the relevant packages?

Comment: Thank you. I installed R4.1.1 and installed packages required. It works now. It could be that previous packages needed to be updated or something. All good now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I installed R version 4.1.1 and installed the packages required and seems to work fine. It seems to be related to error in the previous R version.